# How do I determine how large to make my buffer when using GzipStream?

Tags: .net, gzipstream

I'm trying to decompress a GZipStream. The problem is that the "Length" property on the stream throws a "NotSupported" exception. How do I know what size to make my buffer when I'm reading the bytes from the stream? Since it's compressed I don't know how large the uncompressed version will be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need that?

```
public static byte[] Decompress(this byte[] data)
{
  var ms = new MemoryStream(data);
  var s = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress);

  var output = new MemoryStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
  int read = 0;
  while ((read = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
  {
    output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
  }

  return output.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this example a little bit. I have an HttpResponseStream that is gzipped how do I use this in that context?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to read all the bytes in to a memory stream first just like you do in the decompress routine, and then pass those bytes in. Thanks! Screen scraping sucks.

Comment: Instead of building the `ms` MemoryStream from `data`, you just pass in the HttpResponseStream into the GZipStream instance, I'd say.

Comment: don't forget that both `MemoryStream` and `GZipStream` implement `IDisposable` interface...  As shown, your method will leak memory

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are going to do with it you could write the uncompressed contents to either a MemoryStream or FileStream. They can both be set up to extend their buffers as needed.

The MemoryStream also has a ToArray method that extracts its contents as a byte array.